# Removing values that are lower until the end in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<int,List<Thing>>`

A Thing has 2 fields, an Id, and a Level.

Inside each Thing list, you will never find 2 Things with the same Id.

The key of the dictionary is time and it is increasing.
As time increases, a Thing's level is allowed to increase and decrease, but the last level for that value should be the highest level it reached.

For example with 2 Things:

```
T=1,LV=3,LV=4
T=2,LV=4,LV=4
T=3,LV=4,LV=4
T=4,LV=3,LV=2
T=5,Lv=2,LV=4
T=6,LV=3,LV=3
T=7     ,LV=3
```

After this process the dictionary will now look like:

```
T=1,LV=3,LV=4
T=2,LV=4,LV=4
T=3,LV=4,LV=4
T=4,    ,LV=2
T=5,    ,LV=4
T=6,    ,
T=7     ,
```

In a nutshell:

```
ThingIds = GetAllThingIds()
foreach thingId in thingIds
Find highest level of thing
from lastSecond to firstSecond
let thingAtSecond = secondThings[thingId];
if thingAtSecond.Level == highestLevel then break;
else remove this thing at this second
```

Comment: Still  not clear. Do you want to modify the list by removing all `Thing` which `LV` is higher than the next thing's `LV`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes exactly, we only modify the list, never get rid of it.

Comment: So what's what you want? Delete that "invalid" thing so that always the last is the highest?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, if thing not valid, remove from list at that second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to remove all `Thing` from the list which `Level` is higher than last thing's `Level`?

```
foreach (List<Thing> things in ThingIds.Values) // loop dictionary values, only the lists are relevant
{
    if (things.Count < 2) 
        continue;  // cannot contain invalid "things"
    Thing lastThing = things[things.Count - 1];
    for (int i = things.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--) // backwards loop to remove via index
    {
        Thing t = things[i];
        if (t.Level > lastThing.Level)
            things.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not account for the fact that Things can fluctuate level in the middle of the list, but thank you anyways :) (ex: 4,4,4,4,2,4 is a legal end state)

Comment: @jmasterx: what should hapen with this illegal list: `4,4,4,4,2,3`. Should it contain `2,3` afterwards?

Comment: 4,4,4,4,2,3 => 4,4,4,4

Comment: @jmasterx: ok, i thought that the last value would always be valid.

Comment: No the last value must be the highest value obtained during the life of this thing.

Comment: Why is `T=4,LV=3,LV=2` then `T=4,LV=2` nd not `T=4,LV=3`? Look at your sample

Comment: My example, I admit may have been confusing, but we have a dictionary where each value of the dictionary contains a list of many independent Things. You need to read it vertically, not horizontally.

Comment: Imagine you are tracking traffic and taking a snapshot of car velocities at each second, each car has an id and a velocity at each second. The car's speed fluctuates and has a highest velocity, eventually the car slows down to stop, we want to track these slowdowns and remove them.

Comment: Good example. But i don't understand your samples anyway. Why you remove the "things" from the last two lists? They only contain the maximum values.

Comment: T=1,LV=3,LV=4 Means: At Time 1, I have a car with a speed of 3, and an independent car with a speed of 4. We want to do this process on each individual car. One car might start slowing at T=50, another might start slowing at T=100... etc

Comment: In my example, car 1 started slowing at T=4 and the other started slowing at T=6

Comment: @jmasterx: now i got it. So you have to compare the same car one a different time(dictionary entry)? Then the ID is important, why have you omitted it from your sample?

Comment: Yeah, each entry of the dictionary contains a snapshot of the car velocities in traffic at Second T where T is the dictionary key.